# Looking C++ code example resources

Tags: c++

I am Newbie to C++ and Looking for some book/URL which has lot of C++ code related questions/examples like - 
What is output of this program or what is bug in this program??

Want to read lot of C++ code(Least/moderate complexity first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Bug of the Month](http://www.gimpel.com/html/bugs.htm) - if you really want to find the bug.

Comment: Good resource for intermediate C++ programmers.

Answer (score 2):

[Examples about Stl library](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/idx.html), from The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference - Josuttis

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to have a look at this : [C puzzles](http://www.gowrikumar.com/c/)

Answer (score 1):

[Guru of the week](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/)

Comment: It's probably worth noting that some of the guru of the week questions are now quite old, especially with the release of the C++11 standard. The collected, expanded and improved questions and answers from that site are also available in book form as "Exceptional C++", "More Exceptional C++" and (to a lesser degree) "Exceptional C++ Style", all of which are excellent resources in a Q&A style (one could even say they were exceptional!)